# How to generate Group By and Avg Report for Associative array with mixed column values

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have this data array

```php
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [mclass] => 9
            [mname] => Astik
            [mmarks] => 480
            [midno] => M199
            [fclass] => 10B
            [fname] => Priya
            [fmarks] => 490
            [fidno] => F200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [mclass] => 9
            [mname] => Vikas
            [mmarks] => 470
            [midno] => M129
            [fclass] => 10B
            [fname] => Sakshi
            [fmarks] => 480
            [fidno] => F205
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [mclass] => 9
            [mname] => Tejas
            [mmarks] => 476
            [midno] => M220
            [fclass] => 10B
            [fname] => Kriya
            [fmarks] => 499
            [fidno] => F108
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [mclass] => 10
            [mname] => Mishra
            [mmarks] => 499
            [midno] => M390
            [fclass] =>  
            [fname] =>  
            [fmarks] =>  
            [fidno] =>  
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [mclass] => 
            [mname] => 
            [mmarks] => 
            [midno] =>  
            [fclass] => 10
            [fname] => Vani
            [fmarks] => 500
            [fidno] => F360
        )

)
```

I am not sure how to put a row breaks to get
1. Boys average wait until all Girls listing are done
2. Avg are displayed.

I have no control over this mixed-sequential stored array. At max, I can split that array as Boy array and Girl array but how to display will be another scope of query. For now with this data I m finding hard to get to format of display as described.

Following is the output I get with the below code

```
    Boys    Marks   Girls   Marks
    Astik   480 Priya   490
    Vikas   470 Sakshi  480
    Tejas   476 Kriya   499
    Mishra  499 Vani    500
```

Code I have tried is

```php
foreach ($bsarr as $bkey => $bvalue) {
    if (isset($bvalue['mname']) && isset($bvalue['fname']) ){
        echo "<tr> <td>".$bvalue['mname']."</td><td>".$bvalue['mmarks']."</td><td></td><td>".$bvalue['fname'] ."</td><td>".$bvalue['fmarks']."</td></tr>"; 
    }

    if (isset($bvalue['mname']) && !isset($bvalue['fname']) ){
        echo "<tr> <td>".$bvalue['mname']."</td><td>".$bvalue['mmarks']."</td><td></td><td>  </td><td>  </td></tr>";

    }
    if (!isset($bvalue['mname']) &&  isset($bvalue['fname']) ){
        echo  "<tr><td></td><td>  </td><td></td><td>".$bvalue['fname'] ." </td> <td>".$bvalue['fmarks']."</td><td></td></tr>"; 
    }
 }
```

I expect breaks 9th class Boys' marks, side by side 10th class Girls' marks and later 10th boys below 9th boys avg.

```
            Boys    Marks   Girls   Marks
            Astik   480     Priya   490
            Vikas   470     Sakshi  480
            Tejas   476     Kriya   499
                            Vani    500
                   Avg  xxx         Avg xxx
               ------------        ------------
            Mishra  499
                    Avg xxx
               ------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table isn't well optimized for this task.

1. You should have a profile table which is structured like this:

   ```
   Profile (idno, name, gender)
   ```
2. You should have a table for the classes structured like this:

   ```
   ClassRoom (id_PK, class_title)
   ```
3. You should have another table which stores the different score items for each student with this structure:

   ```
   Scores (id_PK, profile_id, class_id, score)
   ```

That way, you do not have to struggle with having both male and female students of a class have their data in one row. You also can query the database and run thr Group By and Avg SQL aggregation functions easily. You can also order by gender.

Try this to see if it helps.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks Nwamaife, I have no control of DB things. I have been given only the Array model part and I have to use that to do the report views. That's where I am struck for the output as they expect it..